# Language with Block scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

I was reading about function scope vs. block scope. And learnt that Javascript has function scope.

Now when I think about it, all the languages that I know of have function scope. I really dont know of any language having block scope. Can you guys please point me to some language having block scope?

One more doubt, in a language that has block scoping, how would one access the index value of a for loop outside the loop block? What is the advantage of having block scope?

Thanks.

Comment: C, C++, C#, VisualBasic.NET and many many more have block scope.

Comment: JavaScript now has block scope using let to instead of var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALGOL 60 was the first to use the block scope followed by many like `C, C++, C#`...etc

Check out the [Block scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope) section of this Wikipedia page.

> **Advantage of having Block scope**
>
> Blocks are primarily used for control flow, such as with if, while,
>   and for loops, and in these cases block scope means the scope of
>   variable depends on the structure of a function's flow of execution.
>   However, languages with block scope typically also allow the use of
>   "naked" blocks, whose sole purpose is to allow fine-grained control of
>   variable scope. For example, an auxiliary variable may be defined in a
>   block, then used (say, added to a variable with function scope) and
>   discarded when the block ends, or a while loop might be enclosed in a
>   block that initializes variables used inside the loop that should only
>   be initialized once.

Answer (score -3):

> "In JavaScript blocks do not have scope. Only functions have scope. Do
>   not use blocks except as required by the compound statements."

Said by Douglas Crockford

Comment: that does not answer his question